# Get this empty folders and error in Project View Andoid Studio

Tags: android, project

I all of a sudden (actually a while ago, but it only bothers me now that I started to work on that app again) just got these empty folders in my app under the Project view. It only shows in the Project view. Those folders are empty. The app still runs fine under the emulator.

I would appreciate help fixing those.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they aren't causing any harm/hindrance while building your project, then you can try deleting them. Android Studio will automatically warn you if there any usages of a directory/file which you're trying to delete.

Thanks to Jetbrains for this amazing feature.

Comment: Cool! They must have been created through accidental drag-drop while coding. It actually happens with me too sometimes.